# Replace multiple instances of PHP

Tags: php, string, replace, preg-replace

i'm just wondering how I can replace multiple instances of - with just one using php,

for example say I have

```
test----test---3
```

what could I do to replace the multiple instances of - with just 1 so it would be

```
test-test-3
```

thanks :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remove every repeating character:

```
$string = 'test----test---3';
echo preg_replace('{(.)\1+}','$1',$string);
```

Remove specific repeating character:

```
$string = 'test----test---3';
echo eregi_replace("-{2,}", "-", $string);
```

Remove specific repeating character the 'ugly' way:

```
$string = 'test----test---3';
echo implode('-',array_filter(explode('-',$string)));
```

Result for all snippets:

```
test-test-3
```

Comment: the thing is i just want to replace the -'s not other chars, any idea for doing it just the -'s?

Answer (score 2):

Uhm...

```
function replaceDashes($str){
    while(strpos($str,'--')!==false)
        $str=str_replace('--','-',$str);
    return $str;
}
```

You can make it "faster" be replacing:

```
        $str=str_replace('--','-',$str);
```

With:

```
        $str=str_replace(array('----','---','--'),'-',$str);
```

Answer (score 1):

As eregi_replace and ereg_replace is depreciated in PHP5, you can also try

```
preg_replace("/-{2,}/", "-", $string);
```

So if you run

```
preg_replace("/-{2,}/", "-", "--a--b---c----")
```

it will return

> -a-b-c-